# unable to find Near Most Atm in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing small application to find nearest atm.

In this i found my location now i am making request to access the google places.

When i start my app it initially shows me my location but after some seconds it automatically crashes.

I am unable to solve log cat.

It shows some error but how to trace it out.

here is my logcat.

```
09-24 17:09:16.671: E/AndroidRuntime(12415): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
09-24 17:09:16.671: E/AndroidRuntime(12415):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
09-24 17:09:16.671: E/AndroidRuntime(12415):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
09-24 17:09:16.671: E/AndroidRuntime(12415):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
09-24 17:09:16.671: E/AndroidRuntime(12415):    at com.project.kamani.nearby.Map$ParserTask.onPostExecute(Map.java:305)
09-24 17:09:16.671: E/AndroidRuntime(12415):    at com.project.kamani.nearby.Map$ParserTask.onPostExecute(Map.java:1)
09-24 17:09:16.671: E/AndroidRuntime(12415):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-24 17:09:16.671: E/AndroidRuntime(12415):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-24 17:09:16.671: E/AndroidRuntime(12415):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
```

**here i note posted the full logcat i just put some lines in which i think it may showing error.**

Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (isGooglePlayAvailable()) {

        criteria = new Criteria();

        setContentView(R.layout.mapdemo);

        getGoogleMap();

        getUserLocation();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude:" + lat + " Longitude:" + lang,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        getAddress(lat, lang);

        drawMarker(lat, lang);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("location=" + lat + "," + lang);
        sb.append("&radius=5000");
        sb.append("&types=atm");
        sb.append("&name=ATM");
        sb.append("&sensor=false");
        sb.append("&key=my api key");

        PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

        placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
}
```

**Here up to drawmarker() is working correctly.**

Here is the code of Places Task class.

```
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    String data = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        ParserTask parsertask = new ParserTask();

        parsertask.execute(result);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of Parser Task.

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    JSONObject jObject;

    @Override
    protected Place[] doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        Place[] places = null;

        PlaceJSonParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSonParser();

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }

        return places;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Place[] places) {

        mplace = places;

        for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
            Place place = places[i];

            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(place.mLat);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(place.mLang);

            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            Marker ATM_MARKER = drawATMMarker(latlng);

            mHMReference.put(ATM_MARKER.getId(), place);
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the code of downloadurl method. i don't know why its not working.

```
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }
    return data;
}
```

I just really crashed.

Thanks for Support to find bug in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strong textAs the logcat mentions the problem is with the onPostExecute method. The issue is caused when you are doing the following:

```
 double latitude = Double.parseDouble(place.mLat);
 double longitude = Double.parseDouble(place.mLang);
```

Looks like the value being returned by either **place.mLat** or **place.mLang** is a **" "** as you see in the logcat. You might have to check the value being returned.

Comment: Now i modified my code and put the toast just below this getting latitude and longitude so now the toast is displayed it gives only latitude not longitude as well the application now not crashes and still it does not show additional markers can you tell me what can be the problem?And why it only returns only Latitude not longitude?

Comment: Hey bro Thanks it shows all the latitude but why longitude remains 0.0? as i told you it shows the toast containing the latitude but longitude is 0.0 can you tell me why it happens?